# ArgumentError somewhere along the way from my ajax call to my ActionMailer

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making an ajax call. When I press send, I want to send an email, but I'm not even getting into anything in my controller action. It's as though the ajax call is messing up. I am sending three strings in the ajax call.

I honestly don't know what is wrong and am completely baffled by it.

Edit: After some testing, I am positive the error happens on the journey from my AJAX call to my server. I have no idea why.

Ajax:

```
send: function() {
    var data = $('.sendEmail').serializeJSON();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/emails/send',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function(res) {
        console.log("oh yes!");
      },
      error: function(what) {
        console.log(what);
      }
    });
  }
```

Route:

```
post 'emails/send', :to => "emails#send"
```

Controller Action:

```
def send
    email = params['email']
     Mailer.email(email['recipients'], current_user.email, email['subject'], email['content']).deliver!

     render :json => email
  end
```

Mailer method:

```
def email(recipient, sender, subject, content)
    mail(:to => recipient, :from => sender, :body => content, :content_type => "text/html", :subject => subject)
  end
```

Error:

```
Started POST "/emails/send" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-30 06:06:40 -0600
Processing by EmailsController#send as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>{"recipients"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "subject"=>"wowowowow", "content"=>"omgomgomgomg"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 0):
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'.......
```

Comment: Okay, so I just tested this on Heroku in my Rails console and I know for a fact that the Mailer works. if I just call it, it works. The error is somewhere between the AJAX call and getting to my server.

Comment: are there any before or around filters in that action?